# Почему код выдает ошибку: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_proxy():
    html = requests.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    trs = soup.find('table', id='proxylisttable').find_all('tr')[1:11]

    proxies = []

    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        ip = tds[0].text.strip()
        port = tds[1].text.strip()
        schema = 'https' if 'yes' in tds[6].text.strip() else 'http'
        proxy = {'schema': schema, 'address': ip + ':' + port}
        proxies.append(proxy)


def get_html(url):
    proxies = {'https': 'ipaddress:5000'}
    p = get_proxy() # {'schema': '', 'address': ''}
    proxy = {p['schema']: p['address']}
    r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
    return r.json()['origin']


def main():
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip'
    print(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Программа возвращает следующую ошибку:

> File "/home/qwerty0571/Downloads/1Уроки/12_proxy/source/main.py", line 25, in get_html
>      proxy = {p['schema']: p['address']}
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

При этом в функции get_proxy переменная proxy выдает нормальный словарь из 10-ти строк, но 11 строка - none, почему так?

Почему программа выдает ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас метод `get_proxy` ничего не возвращает. Добавьте `return proxies`. Будьте внимательны, у вас метод возвращает список словарей, а не словарь, т.е. вот так вы к нему обратиться не сможете:

```
proxy = {p['schema']: p['address']}
```

Чтобы из результата `get_proxy` что-то достать, придется использовать индекс или цикл по всем прокси из результата, например:

```
proxies = {}
for proxy in p:
    proxies[proxy['schema']] = proxy['address']}
```